# How to execute custom javascript functions in Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpacker

With the arrival of Webpacker to Ruby On Rails, I can't find a way to use my JavaScript functions.

I have a file called `app-globals.js` with a function to test:

```js
function alerts() {
  alert("TEST")
}
```

Then I want to use it in one of my views:

```html
<% = button_tag 'Button', type: 'button', onClick: 'alerts ()'%>
```

But when I press the button, this error is shown in the browser console:

`ReferenceError: alerts is not defined`

1. I placed the `app-globals.js` file in `"app/javascript"` and in `"app/ javascript/packs/application.js"` I placed require ("app-globals").
2. I moved app-globals.js to `"app/javascript/packs"` and removed the require ("app-globals") from `application.js`.

With either case, an error still appears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails 5/6: How to include JS functions with webpacker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501241/rails-5-6-how-to-include-js-functions-with-webpacker)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a workaround, though. You can:

change the function signatures from:

```
function myFunction() { ... }
```

to:

```
window.myFunction = function() { ... }
```

So in your code we can do like below :-

```
app/javascript/packs/app-globals.js

window.alerts = function() {
    alert ("TEST");
}
```

and then require this file to application.js :-

```
app/javascript/packs/application.js

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()

require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")

import $ from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;


require("packs/app-globals") ## require your file
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to do it.  The question is a dup, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501241/rails-5-6-how-to-include-js-functions-with-webpacker/56549843 and my correct answer there.

Comment: Note that part of this answer is copied/pasted from the wrong answer at the earlier question.

Comment: This is not the wrong answer, I have implemented the same in my Rails 6 project which is successfully worked. Currently I am also working with Rails 6 app.
You can see this comment **Maybe all above works – Alexander Gorg** he is also pinting the same thing.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  Yes, it works, but it's not the correct way to use the new javascript packs.  See my correct answer at the link above.

Comment: This worked for me but only for one function. When I tried to do multiple functions (i.e. window.showNum() window.showAlph() window.myFunction() ) - it totally stopped working.