# Rails 6 JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to implement some JavaScript in my Rails 6 app, I have no idea if I'm going about it the right way but so far everything I've tried has been wrong.

I have a file `javascripts/form_helpers/submit.js` for now it just looks like this:

```
const submit_action() {
  console.log("hello world");
}
```

In `javascripts/application.js` I have

```
require("form_helpers"); 
# I've also tried require("form_helpers/submit.js") but I thought I could just include the directory which seems to be what Rails ships with for channels
```

Then in the actual view I have a `form_with` tag:

```
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit', class: "button button-create button-log-radius", onclick: "submit_action()" %>
```

I always get a reference error when I click the submit button that submit_action is not defined.
Am I on the right track here?  Am I way off base?  I'm a little confused by this new javascript folder, am I using it right or should I be putting scripts like this into the assets directory?

BTW I've seen this question asked before on here and the answer had to do with appending `window` before your function name ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501241/rails-5-6-how-to-include-js-functions-with-webpacker)) but that feels hacky to me.

Comment: Can you check if the javascript has loaded in browser? If yes, put a debugger and see if the control is reaching the submit_action() method.

Comment: If I change the sbumit.js function to: `debugger; const submit_action() {
  console.log("hello world");
}` it will pause the browser when the page loads but will still say "uncaught reference error, submit_action not defined"

Comment: Do you see the submit.js in developer tools -> sources when the page is loaded or when the debugger is hit?

Comment: Yeah, when the debugger pauses the page the entirety of submit.js shows.

Comment: Try this:
Adding the js file in app/javascript/packs

In the end of application.html.erb file add this
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'custom', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

Next,
rake assets:precompile

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this.  Unfortunately, no luck, the debugger will still pause if I leave it in but then it says submit_action is not defined.

Comment: Don't mention. Were you able to figure out what caused the issue?

Comment: Thanks for following up, I never got it working. this is just a personal project so I just switched to another branch and started working on some other things.