# WebPack vs Asset Pipeline in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, asset-pipeline, webpack-dev-server

As a beginner in Rails 6, Sometimes I really confused about I follow a web pack or asset pipeline.
In Rails 6, I know Webpack is used by default for JS. Why only JS why not for SCSS?. I know it should be customized to use also for SCSS.

According to my understanding. All the things which are installed through yarn will use WebPack by Default. Anything else which are installed through GEM is under Asset Pipeline. I think this is the point that differentiates WebPack and Asset Pipeline. Correct me if I am wrong.

Also, describe some differences between WebPack and Asset Pipeline? Why do Rails use by Default Webpack for JS? What are the limitations of the Asset Pipeline? If WebPack is Faster than Asset Pipeline then why only JS not for CSS/SCSS by default?

Thank you. Hoping for a better and positive reply.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is way too broad to be answered here. Discussion is held e.g. at https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/ but also on many other places all over the web (look out for conference talks as well). Its complicated and there is no objective answer. I will vote to close this question. If somebody can put good read-up resources for Hassam in the comment here that would be very nice.

Comment: The problem with Sprockets (the old assets pipeline) is that it did not integrate with front-end package distribution systems like NPM or Yarn and relied on the community to make gemified versions of these packages. If you wanted to use something that was not available as a gem you would have to download it manually or integrate Webpack or some other package manager anyways. It was pretty great back when rails was one of the only frameworks to ship with an assets pipeline but is completely obsolete today.

Comment: @max can you verify this?
All the things which are installed through yarn will use WebPack by Default. Anything else which are installed through GEM is under Asset Pipeline.